# Extract multiple values from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I need to extract values from a string.

```
string sTemplate = "Hi [FirstName], how are you and [FriendName]?"
```

Values I need returned:

- FirstName
- FriendName

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That is more a parse or extract then a split. A split would keep everything.  And that is not a string array.  I edited

Comment: Will the words you want always be surrounded by "[" and "]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) globally:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Explanation:

```
\[ : [ is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.
(.*?) : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
\] : ] is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.
```

Example:

```
string input = "Hi [FirstName], how are you and [FriendName]?";
string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
       Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format/structure of the text won't be changing at all, and assuming the square brackets were used as markers for the variable, you could try something like this:

```
string sTemplate = "Hi FirstName, how are you and FriendName?"

// Split the string into two parts. Before and after the comma.
string[] clauses = sTemplate.Split(',');

// Grab the last word in each part.
string[] names = new string[]
{
    clauses[0].Split(' ').Last(), // Using LINQ for .Last()
    clauses[1].Split(' ').Last().TrimEnd('?')
};
return names;
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to tokenize the text and then extract the terms.

```
string[] tokenizedTerms = new string[7];
char delimiter = ' ';

tokenizedTerms = sTemplate.Split(delimiter);

firstName = tokenizedTerms[1];
friendName = tokenizedTerms[6];

char[] firstNameChars = firstName.ToCharArray();
firstName = new String(firstNameChars, 0, firstNameChars.length - 1);

char[] friendNameChars = lastName.ToCharArray();
friendName = new String(friendNameChars, 0, friendNameChars.length - 1);
```

Explanation:

 You tokenize the terms, which separates the string into a string array with each element being the char sequence between each delimiter, in this case between spaces which is the words. From this word array we know that we want the 3rd word (element) and the 7th word (element). However each of these terms have punctuation at the end. So we convert the strings to a char array then back to a string minus that last character, which is the punctuation. 
*Note:

This method assumes that since it is a first name, there will only be one string, as well with the friend name. By this I mean if the name is just Will, it will work. But if one of the names is Will Fisher (first and last name), then this will not work.*

Comment: This assumes the tokens are always in the same location.  But you're not even using the correct indexes, the first name would be at index 1 and the last name at index 6.

Comment: All of these answers are based on them being in the same location. And he even stated that he wants it based on that template.

Comment: Ali's answer doesn't assume position.  And the OP didn't mention a template.  They just say they want to extract from a string and gave an example.

Comment: Then why is the variable named sTemplate --> "string template"... It is implied and if it is not implied and the data can be contained in any sentence structure, then that requires a lot more code and knowledge of NLP.

Comment: It likely means that the string is a template that contains values in brackets that should be replaced with actual values at some point.  Not that this is the only arrangement for word that the OP would ever want to deal with.  But the is some ambiguity here.